# Overload of parentheses operator - passing an argument to predicate functions

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, predicate

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/356993) example of operator() overload is clear and straightforward:

```
struct add_x {
  add_x(int val) : x(val) {}  // Constructor
  int operator()(int y) const { return x + y; }
private:
  int x;
};
add_x add42(42);
int i = add42(8);
assert(i == 50);
```

`add_x add42(42)` defines a functor with 42 set as private member, next `int i = add42(8)` calls this functor with 8 as argument. Next `operator()` adds 42 and 8 and returns 50. Just great.

However, how on earth does [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) example work:

```
 std::vector<int> v(10, 2);
// some code here
struct DivisibleBy
    {
        const int d;
        DivisibleBy(int n) : d(n) {}
        bool operator()(int n) const { return n % d == 0; }
    };
 
    if (std::any_of(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), DivisibleBy(7)))
        std::cout << "At least one number is divisible by 7\n";
```

`DivisibleBy(7)` creates an instance of `DivisibleBy` with 7 set as struct member. How does `any_of()` realize that it  has to pass vector values to `DivisibleBy` used here as a predicate function?
This definitely works:

```
    if (std::any_of(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), [](int i) {
        DivisibleBy db7 = DivisibleBy(7);
        return db7(i);} ))
        std::cout << "At least one number is divisible by 7\n";
```

I define an inline predicate function with explicit `int i` argument which receives values defined by iterators. However, the former example (`any_of(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), DivisibleBy(7))`) has no argument to catch values from iteration.
I assume this

```
bool operator()(int n) const
```

is the place where magic happens, but cannot find any explicit reference how exactly does it work?

Comment: Yes the operator function is called on each element of the vector. If any of the elements lead to returning true from the operator function, then the `any_of` returns true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `DivisibleBy(7)` creates a temporary object, which is passed to `std::any_of`. This objects function-call operator is called as usual.

It's similar to:

```
DivisibleBy by7(7);
if (std::any_of(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), by7))
    std::cout << "At least one number is divisible by 7\n";
```

Comment: I think I can see now:
*p - unary predicate .
The expression p(v) must be convertible to bool for every argument v*